# Expectation - $n$ balls taken out of a box

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

From a box with n numbered with $1$ to $n$ balls we two times choose at random one ball with replacement. Let $X$ denote the biggest of the number which appeared on a chose balls. Find a distribution of $X$ and find $\mathbb{E}X$.

How to find that? I know that distribution is $$\frac{1}{n} P(Y \le k) {2 \choose 1} +\frac{1}{n^2}$$ but i have utterly no idea why.

How to find $\mathbb{E}X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- What is the probability the first chosen ball is $k$ or less?
- What is the probability the second chosen ball is $k$ or less?
- What is the probability both chosen balls are $k$ or less? This is $\mathbb{P}(X \le k)$
- What is $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\mathbb{P}(X \le k)-\mathbb{P}(X \le k-1)$?
- What is $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k \,\mathbb{P}(X=k)$?

Comment: could you be a bit more specific when it comes to distribution i think i will manage to do the $\mathbb{E}X$

Comment: @mkropkowski What do you get for the answers to any of my questions?

Comment: Probability that $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{n}^2$ thats what i know.

Comment: *What is the probability the first chosen ball is $k$ or less?* is not a difficult question

Comment: I guess it is what i wrote as a part of this question.

Comment: The probability the first chosen ball is $k$ or less is $\displaystyle\frac{k}{n}$.   Similarly, the probability the second chosen ball is $k$ or less is $\displaystyle\frac{k}{n}$.  The probability both chosen balls are $k$ or less  is then $\displaystyle\mathbb{P}(X \le k) = \frac{k^2}{n^2}$.  So $\displaystyle\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\mathbb{P}(X \le k)-\mathbb{P}(X \le k-1) =\frac{k^2}{n^2} - \frac{(k-1)^2}{n^2} = \frac{2k-1}{n^2}$.  This makes $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k=1}^n k \,\mathbb{P}(X=k) =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(2k-1)}{n^2} = \frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}{6}$